# Scalar function NLV2 not found on DB2 9.7

Tags: function, db2

I'm using DB2 V9.7.11. I found scalar function `NVL2` in IBM official documentation for db2 LUW, which version is 9.7. But when I used this function in my sql statement, it returned:

```
No authorized routine named "NVL2" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.23.42
```

Does the official document make a mistake? Or some operations need to be done? Hope somebody can do some help. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to add facts. (1) __show your SQL code__ that is using the `NVL2` function, and (2) show proof that `db2updv97` was run against the database after fp11 was applied.

Answer (score 0):

`NVL2` takes three parameters, E.g.

```
VALUES NVL2(1,2,3)
```

returns

```
2
```

if you call it with two or fewer you will get the error message that you posted.

Therefore unless you show your SQL I suspect you are not calling it with the correct number of parameters.

Comment: I'm sure I used this function exactly as the document said. Even I copy your statement to execute, I still get the same error.

Comment: maybe try `VALUES SYSIBM.NVL2(1,2,3)`  otherwise, run `db2updv97` against the database as maybe the function came in in some fixpack, but you have not run the update to enable new functions

Comment: I ran that command, and got "db2updv97 completed successfully for database 'xxxx'. ". But still I can't use nvl2: `SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "NVL2" of type "FUNCTION" having 
compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884`

Comment: Not sure I can help. I don't have a DB2 9.7 install to test possibilities on. 9.7 is long out of support, so I would suggest upgrading to a supported version, and in the meantime just use CASE, or create your own SQL UDF that implements the NVL2 logic.  You can even call is NVL2 and if it is in a schema in your function path, you can use it just as well at the inbuilt verions